Android: Can't rename SIM card - SIM name already in use
I'm trying to rename a eSim card on my Samsung phone (Android 14)

But I get the following error ("SIM name already in use"):

It's because previously I had use this name for my physical SIM card, but it has been removed and replaced by eSim card, so it's not even there anymore:

This is so annoying. And what am I supposed to do in this case? I mean, it's just a bug...
